# Find Friends-of-Friends in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, relationship

I've got a system with Employees, Projects, and Companies. Relationships among these entities are currently stored in a single SQL table called Relationships. An extra-simplified version of that table would look like this:

```
  EntityID | EntityCategory | TypeID  | AssocType
    123    |    Employee    |   ABC   |  Project
    123    |    Employee    |   DEF   |  Project
    789    |    Company     |   ABC   |  Project
    789    |    Company     |   DEF   |  Project
```

(I should note that the real-world version of this database has more entity types—e.g. Contacts can also be associated with Projects or Employees, hence the Category/Type columns) I want to find which Employees and Companies "know" each other through a mutual relationship with a Project—basically a limited search for friends of friends. We refer to this as an "Indirect Relationship". In SQL, I can do this:

```
SELECT R.EntityID AS EmployeeID, R2.EntityID AS CompanyID, 
Count(R.TypeID) as SharedProjectCount
FROM Relationships as R 
INNER JOIN Relationships as R2 ON 
 R.TypeID=R2.TypeID AND R2.EntityCategory='Company' AND R2.AssocType='Project'
WHERE R.EntityCategory='Employee' AND R.AssocType='Project'
GROUP BY R.EntityID, R2.EntityID
```

And get a result set like:

```
  EmployeeID | CompanyID | SharedProjectCount
      123    |    789    |          2
```

I want to be able to do this in Elasticsearch. The data is stored a little differently:

```
 [
  {EmployeeID:123, ProjectID:ABC},
  {EmployeeID:123, ProjectID:DEF},
  {CompanyID:789,  ProjectID:ABC},
  {CompanyID:789,  ProjectID:DEF}
 ]
```

At the core of my issue is this: I want to pull this relationship data into Elasticsearch in bulk. The direct relationships are all in the SQL table and performant to retrieve. Computing the indirect relationships is hard on SQL, and I would like to try assembling them using Elasticsearch instead. Is there a way that I can request (for example) **all** Employees related to **any** Companies through Projects, retrieving the results from Elasticsearch in a format something like {EmployeeID:123,CompanyID:789,SharedProjectCount:2}?

I already know that something like Neo4j is the best tool for working with a graph like this; please understand that it's not an option, and I'm specifically looking for a way to do with Elasticsearch. I am open to changing the structure of the data in Elasticsearch.

Comment: When you say "new relationship", is that relationship defined by, say, `ProjectID:DEF`?

Comment: A new relationship is defined by a pair of IDs, so in Elasticsearch something like {EmployeeID:456, ProjectID:XYZ}, or in the above SQL table [ 456 | Employee | XYZ | Project ]

Comment: Can you not just do a term query on `ProjectID` and get back all the EmployeeIDs and CompanyIDs that share that ProjectID?

Comment: Upvoted because of course you're right, for my "when a relationship is created" question. Thanks! But with that example I had wandered off my biggest problem, which is about fetching indirectly-related entities from Elasticsearch in big batches. I've edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: Yeah, I mean you basically need a join. ES doesn't do joins, because distributed joins are a fundamentally hard problem. You're probably going to have to do this in code.

Answer (score 0):

Run a `match_all` query with a [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)  aggregation on "project_id" and a [`top_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) sub aggregation.

That should give you a list of EmployeeID and CompanyID records grouped by ProjectID (for all projects).